# Strange! custom object tab or related list not displaying for user

Tags: profile, security, permissions, user, owd

I have custom objects order and quote from managed package and i have given access to both objects in profile with ALL ACCESS (CRUD,view all,modify all).

now, it should display related list or tab for both objects for the profile.

I have assigned same profile and role to another user and by logging in that user i am able to see the tab and related list.

means, user A with same profile and role **not** able to see the tab and user B with same profile and role able to see the tab and related list.

after doing checks got to know that may be their is something messed up with that particular user but i am unable to find it.

any suggestions? do i need to raise the case to salesforce.

Comment: Unlikely but.. for starters Did you chk sharing rules? Is user B the owner of the record or a sharing rule is sharing the record with him.

Comment: Does user B have an additional permission set assigned?

Comment: No permission set assigned to user B... i marked view all and modify all so, sharing rules are overridden... for both objects... so in any way it should display the tab or related list for both objects